# No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.The relevant error-causing widget was FutureBuilder<FirebaseApp>

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

No MediaQuery widget ancestor found.
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder
Scaffold widgets require a MediaQuery widget anchester.The Specific widget that could not find a Mediaquery anchester was:
Scaffold

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todolist/colorshades/color.dart';
import 'package:todolist/database/services.dart';

import 'Loading.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString())),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Loading();
        }
        return MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: TodoList(),
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error indicates that `MediaQuery` was referenced before it was provided to the widget tree (which happens in `MaterialApp` widget in your case). You might want to move your `MaterialApp` widget to the top of your widget tree, above `Scaffold` widget (preferably to the very top, above your `FutureBuilder`).

So it would looke like this (assuming your `TodoList` and `Loading` widgets both contain `Scaffold`, otherwise wrap your `FutureBuilder` in `Scaffold`):

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
  ),
  home: FutureBuilder(
    future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(child: Text(snapshot.error.toString())),
        );
      }
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Loading();
      }
      return TodoList();
    },
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have implemented following steps:

1:  Add dep in pubspecs.yaml

```
firebase_core: // latest version
```

2: Add dependency & service in the app `build.gradle` file.

```
dependencies {

 implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.5.0')
 
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

3: register android app and add **google-service.json** under `app` directory only

4: Initialization in `main.dart`

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much now i was using getx GetMaterial app i though it's something to do with Getx but after reinstalling Firebase core it fixed the issue

Comment: Sounds good :) Keep growing